# Structure of non clustered index in table with clustered index primary key

Tags: sql-server, indexing

Suppose, I have following table structure:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Users]
(
    [Id] [INT] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Age] [INT] NULL,
    [CreationDate] [DATETIME] NOT NULL,
    [DisplayName] [NVARCHAR](40) NOT NULL,
    [Location] [NVARCHAR](100) NULL,

    CONSTRAINT [PK_Users_Id] 
        PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([Id] ASC)
                WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, 
                      IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, 
                      ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

As we can see in the above code, the `[Id]` column is the primary key clustered index column.

Now, I am creating the following two non-clustered indexes:

```
-- Index #1  
CREATE INDEX IX_CreationDate_Id_DisplayName_Age1 
ON dbo.Users(CreationDate, Id) 
INCLUDE (DisplayName, Age); 

-- Index #2  
CREATE INDEX IX_CreationDate_Id_DisplayName_Age2 
ON dbo.Users(CreationDate) 
INCLUDE (DisplayName, Age); 

-- Index #3  
CREATE INDEX IX_CreationDate_Id_DisplayName_Age3 
ON dbo.Users(CreationDate) 
INCLUDE (ID, DisplayName, Age);
```

My questions is as follows: we know that the `Id` column is the primary key clustered index key column, so it will always be part of all non clustered indexes, whether it's added as a non-clustered index key or not.

Then in what scenarios do we need to add the `Id` column to be part of the non-clustered index key explicitly, as its added in Index #1. In all three cases of Index creation, where `Id` columns will be stored in the B-Tree structure of the non-clustered index?

Comment: With the ID column being the primary key there is no requirement to explicitely include it in any non-clustered index, as you've already noted - so what exactly are you asking? You would only need to add ID to support queries where it was not the primary key or clustered index.

Comment: Where the clustered index key is stored in the non-clustered index key pages? in the leaf node pages? if yes, that means its implicitly part of include column list. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

As you noted, since the ID is the primary key, it is always implicitly included as a mechanism to link the non-clustered index back to the table's clustered index.  There is no reason to list it as an included column.

There could be a case, as in your Index #1, where you want to use the PK as part of a composite key to sort the order that the non-clustered index has. However, in your case, if creation dates are typically unique values, it would serve no additional value in terms of the data's sorted order.

Comment: Is there any difference between Index#2 and Index#3? What if I change the ordering of include columns in Index#3: INCLUDE (DisplayName, Id, Age) or INCLUDE (DisplayName, Age, Id), then what would be the difference?

Comment: Include order makes no difference.  And no, there is no difference between the #2 and #3.

Comment: If I don't place Id column (which is clustered index key and primary key) as non-clustered Index Key then it will be part of leaf pages only and not in the index key pages. Correct?

Comment: That is my understanding, yes.

Answer (score 0):

In any index, SQL Server requires that the internal structure of the index should be unique. When a non-clustered index is created on columns that are not otherwise guaranteed to be unique, a *uniqifier* is added. In normal circumstances, this is the clustering key, as that needs to be there anyway.

So adding the clustering key as the *last* key column doesn't add any usefulness, nor does adding it as an `INCLUDE` column. (And the order of `INCLUDE` columns never matters anyway.)

However, adding it as a *non-last* key column means that all columns after that become pointless, as once the B-tree reaches that key level it is unique anyway.

It can still be useful to include the clustering key in the index definition, if there is any reason to suspect that a DBA may later change the clustering key, and you wish for that index to continue to be sorted according to the clustering key.